# How can I catch touchmove events on an element that is added to the DOM after my finger is already on the screen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, touchstart

I am working on a Javascript / html5 project for iPad.

I need to be able to catch touchmove events on an element that does not get added to the `DOM` until after a `touchstart` event has fired (i.e. until after a person has put their finger on the screen.)

I have tried simulating a `touchstart` event and firing it programatically...

```
$( "#container" ).append( element );
element.on( "touchmove", doStuff );
var ev = $.Event( "touchstart" );
element.trigger( ev );
```

...however this does not work.  The only way I can get `doStuff` to start firing is to lift my finger and then touch the screen again, triggering a second `touchstart` event.

How can I catch `touchmove` events on an element that is added to the `DOM` after my finger is already on the screen?

Comment: Is it possible to create a simplified version of this issue on http://jsfiddle.net ? I am not too familiar with the draggables but if I can play around with it, maybe we can figure something out

Comment: Sure, fiddle here:  http://jsfiddle.net/rx4qdtuj/3/

Comment: I am not sure about the triggering of the event but if your goal is to move the box when your finger moves for the first time you touch then you might have to get the x and y of the mouse/touch and move the box accordingly

Comment: The goal is not to drag - my original wording was wrong - the goal is get the touchmove event to start firing on the new element, when my finger brushes over it - without having to lift my finger and put it down again.  For a number reasons I cannot listen to touchstart / touchmove events on a parent element instead - it has to be on the element that is newly added.

Comment: Oh I see, well I can get it to trigger once but it will not recognize the movement from your initial touch

Comment: Yes, movement from the initial touch is what I need.

Comment: Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/myh68yno/) maybe?

Comment: Any reason you don't accept Roamer-1888's solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To summarise, you appear to want :

- on touchstart: to display and position a styled div element.
- on touchmove: to drag the element *without releasing and re-pressing the mouse button*.

If this interpretation is correct, then the answer is to to handle touchmove events on the *same element* that was originally clicked on - namely the "body" element. It is not necessary to handle touchmove events of the element you want to drag (the added element).

There must be many ways to write the code. Here's one, which is probably not exactly what you want (chiefly in the positioning maths) but should be simple to adapt :

```
var $element = $("<div class='element' />");

$("body").on({
    'touchstart mousedown': function (e) {
        $element.appendTo("body");
        $(this).on('touchmove mousemove', move);
        move(e);//you could do `$(this).trigger('touchmove', e)` but a conventional function call keeps `move` simple.
    },
    'touchend mouseup': function (e) {
        $(this).off('touchmove mousemove');
    }
});

function move(e) {
    $element.css({
        left: (e.pageX - 10) + 'px',
        top: (e.pageY - 10) + 'px',
        cursor: 'pointer'
    });
}
```

*mousedown/mousemove/mouseup allow for desktop testing and can be removed for touch device usage.*

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/myh68yno/1/)**

Comment: Thanks for providing a solution within the problem specs.  I've been dealing with the exact same issue as OP.

Comment: Thank you @ChocolateAndCheese, you express more gratitude, indeed more sign of life, than the OP.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need it to trigger once then it is quite easy

```
function addElement() {
    $( "body" ).append( element );

    element.on( "touchmove", doStuff );
    element.trigger("touchmove"); 
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rx4qdtuj/8/

I checked this on my ipad simulator. I replaced the alert with append so you don't get constantly alerted on ipad.

If you want it to continually trigger, the only possible thing I can think of was to fake the touchmove on the created element

http://jsfiddle.net/rx4qdtuj/9/

```
var element = $("<div class='element' />");

$( "body" ).on( "touchstart", addElement );
$(".wrapper").on("touchmove", addElement);

function addElement() {
    $( "body" ).append( element );

    element.on( "touchmove", doStuff );
    element.trigger("touchmove"); 
}

function doStuff() {
    $('body').append('a ')
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper"></div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 100px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}
```

The move actually triggers on the already created div wrapper which is in the same spot as the created element

Comment: Unfortunately I need touchmove to fire on it's own, and repeatedly.

Comment: Ahh - I see.  Unfortunately this doesn't work in my case either.  I cannnot listen to events on a parent element instead  (complicated...)  I can only listen to events on the element that is added to the DOM.

Comment: @user1031947 why not? this element exists for the sole purpose of capturing touchmove. You can use it to do whatever it is needed to the just created element. As a matter of fact, it can be removed after the touchmove has finished. Sorry it is not a parent, it's just another element that is placed at the same place as the created element

Comment: Because IRL this is a webView that is embedded in a steroidsJS layer that does not become visible until after a touchstart event happens in a separate steroids layer.  This is kind of the same as if you have your finger on the screen before the page is loaded and initializes - and then need to detect touchmove events on that once the page has finished initializing, without lifting your finger and putting it down again.

Comment: @user1031947 then honestly I don't think this is an issue at all. If the person has his finger on the screen before anything started to happen, that person would be smart enough to know he needs to do something before anything else starts to happen

Comment: I'm not here to debate workflow - I am just wondering if it is possible to do this.  Appreciate your help regardless.

Comment: @user1031947 I am just saying you might be worried over nothing. I don't think it's possible but I don't really know anything about the js lib that you are using

Comment: Thanks - yes it is a bit of a pain and if I can't figure it out I'll have to rethink things a bit.  I'll let this question sit for awhile and see if any other suggestions come up.

Answer (score -3):

[see documentation draggable function](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/touchevents.shtml)

**applicate you function**

```
<div id="track" class="track">
<div id="box2" style="left:0; top:0">Drag Me</div>
</div>
```

native javascript

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){

 var box2 = document.getElementById('box2'),
 boxleft, // left position of moving box
 startx, // starting x coordinate of touch point
 dist = 0, // distance traveled by touch point
 touchobj = null // Touch object holder

 box2.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e){
  touchobj = e.changedTouches[0] // reference first touch point
  boxleft = parseInt(box2.style.left) // get left position of box
  startx = parseInt(touchobj.clientX) // get x coord of touch point
  e.preventDefault() // prevent default click behavior
 }, false)

 box2.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e){
  touchobj = e.changedTouches[0] // reference first touch point for this event
  var dist = parseInt(touchobj.clientX) - startx // calculate dist traveled by touch point
 // move box according to starting pos plus dist
 // with lower limit 0 and upper limit 380 so it doesn't move outside track:
  box2.style.left = ( (boxleft + dist > 380)? 380 : (boxleft + dist < 0)? 0 : boxleft + dist ) + 'px'
  e.preventDefault()
 }, false)

}, false)
```

Comment: Can you add explanation on what you ave wrote here?

Comment: this on the links at the beginning of my answer, since it is very long

Comment: Then paste or create a short version of the explanation and put it here. If the link is broken one day then there will be no explanation

Comment: clearly explained in the code comments. specifically what is the question.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question.  I am asking how to recognize touchmove events on an element that does not get added to the DOM until after your finger is on the screen, so no touchstart event will fire on it.

Comment: the cycle must start at the first touch, not movement